# Is there a way to handle errors thrown by third party modules in Python?

Tags: python, exception, beautifulsoup

Even with a try/except block, it doesn't seem that Python will catch errors thrown by a function or module called in that block. This doesn't make sense. Is there a specific syntax for it? I can't seem to catch the UnicodeDecodeError that BeautifulSoup throws. I just want to be able to catch the error and copy the contents of temp to temp1 when BeautifulSoup can't read the file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('/mnt/data/opendata/work/temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
        with open('/mnt/data/opendata/work/temp1.txt', 'w') as f1:
            f1.write(str(soup))
    except:
        with open('/mnt/data/opendata/work/temp1.txt', 'w') as f1:
            f1.write(contents)
```

Comment: are you sure? I've just tested this with a module that does nothing but throw a new type of error and it gets caught just fine.  Are you sure it's `BeautifulSoup` that's throwing the error? if `open` or `write` throw an error in your example within the `except` block they will be uncaught

Comment: It might be a setting in your debugger, check your exception settings. I know in visual studio when writing c# you can make the program stop when an error is hit even in a try catch block